# Error al insertar registro SQL Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Estoy realizando una App de productos y no se porque no me los está insertando en SQLITE:
Tengo definidas las siguientes clases: BBDD_Helper, Producto, Insertar. La APP no da error y me crea la BBDD pero no inserta los registros y por más que le doy vueltas no veo el error. Agradecería algo de ayuda.

Clase BBDD_Helper:

```
public class BBDD_Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // Versión BD
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Lista_Productos.db"; // Nombre BD

public BBDD_Helper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory: null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(Estructura_BBDD.SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(Estructura_BBDD.SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
```

}

Aquí va la estructura de la base de datos:

```
public class Estructura_BBDD {
// Nombre tabla BD
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Producto";
// Campos tabla
public static final String NOMBRE_COLUMNA1 = "Id_producto";
public static final String NOMBRE_COLUMNA2 = "Nombre";
public static final String NOMBRE_COLUMNA3 = "Categoria";
public static final String NOMBRE_COLUMNA4 = "Precio";
public static final String NOMBRE_COLUMNA5 = "Cantidad";
public static final String NOMBRE_COLUMNA6 = "Favorito";
// Crear tabla
public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + Estructura_BBDD.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA2 + " TEXT NOT NULL" + "," +
                Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA3 + " TEXT NOT NULL" + "," +
                Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA4 + " FLOAT NOT NULL" + "," +
                Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA5 + " INTEGER NOT NULL" + "," +
                Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA6 + " INTEGER NOT NULL" + ");";
// Borrar tabla
public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Estructura_BBDD.TABLE_NAME;
```

}

Clase insertar:

```
public class Activity_Insertar extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Declarar atributos
    private EditText et_nombreIn, et_categoryIn, et_priceIn, et_cantIn;

    //Crear instancia para definir las acciones a realizar sobre la BD
    final BBDD_Helper helper = new BBDD_Helper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editar);

        //Inicializar componentes
        et_nombreIn = findViewById(R.id.et_nombreIn);
        et_categoryIn = findViewById(R.id.et_categoryIn);
        et_priceIn = findViewById(R.id.et_priceIn);
        et_cantIn = findViewById(R.id.et_cantIn);
        
    }

    public void insertar (View vista){
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA2, et_nombreIn.getText().toString());
        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA3, et_categoryIn.getText().toString());
        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA4, 
                     Float.parseFloat(et_priceIn.getText().toString()));
        values.put(Estructura_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA5, 
                     Integer.parseInt(et_cantIn.getText().toString()));
               
        long newRowId = db.insert(Estructura_BBDD.TABLE_NAME, nullColumnHack:null, values);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registro guardado con éxito" , 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           
        }
    }
```

Cuando lanzo la aplicación, me deja insertar los registros sin ningún problema además tambien me crea la base de datos que la abro con dbBrowser pero las columnas aparecen vacías. También tengo un método para que no me inserte repetidos pero al estar vacía la base de datos no me funciona.
Agradezco mucho vuestra ayuda y toda la luz que me podáis aportar.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente, elimina el cachè o la app del dispositivo , esto para evitar que tengas una estructura incorrecta en tu base de datos.

Define con valor `null` el parametro "nullColumnHack" en la funciòn que realiza la inserciòn:

```
long newRowId = db.insert(Estructura_BBDD.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Prueba nuevamente.

Comment: Así es como lo tengo, lo que pasa que al copiar el código aquí se quita la etiqueta de "nullColumnHack"